# Proof that singleton sets are Borel sets in $\Omega = (0,1]$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-sets

I’m reading the following definition and lemma, and I’d like to ask some questions.

> **Definition 7.3**
> (a) Consider $\Omega=(0,1] .$ Let $\mathcal{C}_{0}$ be the collection of all open intervals in $(0,1] .$ Then $\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}_{0}\right)$, the $\sigma-$ algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}_{0}$, is called the Borel $\sigma$ - algebra. It is denoted by $\mathcal{B}((0,1])$.
> (b) An element of $\mathcal{B}((0,1])$ is called a Borel-measurable set, or simply a Borel set.
> Thus, every open interval in $(0,1]$ is a Borel set. We next prove that every singleton set in $(0,1]$ is a Borel set.
>
> **Lemma 7.4** Every singleton set $\{b\}, 0<b \leq 1$, is a Borel set, i.e., $\{b\} \in \mathcal{B}((0,1])$.
>
> **Proof:** Consider the collection of sets set $\left\{\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right), n \geq 1\right\} .$ By the definition of Borel sets.
> $$
> \left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right) \in \mathcal{B}((0,1]) .
> $$
> Using the properties of $\sigma$ -algebra,
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{c} \in \mathcal{B}((0,1]) \\
> \Longrightarrow & \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{c} \in \mathcal{B}((0,1]) \\
> \Longrightarrow &\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{c} \in \mathcal{B}((0,1]) \\
> \Longrightarrow & \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right) \in \mathcal{B}((0,1]) .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Next, we claim that
> $$
> \{b\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right) .
> $$
> i.e., $b$ is the only element in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. We prove this by contradiction. Let $h$ be an element in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ other than $b$. For every such $h$, there exists a large enough $n_{0}$ such that $h \notin$ $\left(b-\frac{1}{n_{0}}, b+\frac{1}{n_{0}}\right) .$ This implies $h \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right) .$ Using $(7.1)$ and $(7.2)$, thus, proves that $\{b\} \in$
> $\mathcal{B}((0,1])$

1. I’m having a bit of trouble understanding what a typical element of $\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}_{0}\right)$ would be (or in general, what an element of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set is). Would it be correct to say that, if $F \in \sigma\left(\mathcal{C}_{0}\right)$, then either $F = \Omega \setminus S$, where $S$ is a countable union of open intervals in $\Omega$, or $F$ itself is a countable union of open intervals in $\Omega$?
2. In the proof, when checking that $\{b\} \in \mathcal{B}((0,1])$, are we only checking that the complement of $\{b\}$ is in $\mathcal{B}((0,1])$?
3. In the first sentence of the proof, for a fixed $b$, isn’t it true that not all $n$’s work?

Comment: That is one way to do it. A more direct way to do it is by noticing that if $0<x<1$, then $(0,1]\setminus\{x\}=(0,x)\cup(x,1]$ which is open in $I=(0,1]$, and for $x=1$, $I\setminus\{x\}=(0,1)$ which is open in $I$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz could you have a look at the questions at the end? At least for question 1. Thanks. I’m new to this so I need a bit of details to make sure there’s no misunderstanding of what’s going on.

Comment: The Borel sigma Algebra is generated by the collection of open sets. The class of Borel sets in particular contains countable unions of open sets as well as countable intersections of one sets. There are many more Borel sets, of course and then can be weird.  Your assertion in (1) is not correct. The set of irrationals for instance is a Borel set and neither this nor its complement is the union of open sets.